# When opening a workbook it opens in the window of another workbook (Excel 2010)

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a problem with the setup of Excel on my new PC. When i have a workbook open in excel and want to open another one the second is opened in the same Excel window meaning that i cant view one workbook on each of my two screens. How do I chose that each file i open should open in a seperate Excel session. Also when i use the function 'New Window' the new window is in the samme Excel session, again resulting in me not being able to view the two windows on different screens.[Image of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAKEK.png)

Comment: That's how it worked back in Excel 2010. 
If you require a second window, then you need to open a second instance of Excel, not a new workbook. Do it by clicking middle mouse button on the Excel logo on your task bar, then open your second Excel in there.

Comment: Wow that is stupid, thanks for the reply